# Updating Fragments - FrameStatePagerAdapter and HTTP Calls

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have been searching for an answer to my problem, but I seem to get none, despite of how many tutorials I followed, how many questions I've gone through and how many things I've tried to do what I want. Basically, I stumbled upon some good tips, and still couldn't manage to do what wanted.

**THE PROBLEM**

I am creating an Android Application that will use Fragments (alongside with tabs). In these fragments, I have crucial information relating the application, such as text boxes, and buttons. However, I want to do something really simple, which is updating one of my fragments as I come back to it (imagine I swipe back to a fragment, and I update it with the relevant information). Where is the information stored? On a node.js server, to which I call every time I want information. So for that, I created the following structure.

**THE STRUCTURE**

First of all, I started off creating my Activity.

```
public class CentralActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    CentralPagerAdapter mCentralActivity;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_central);
        tabHandler();
    }

    public void tabHandler() {
        mCentralActivity = new CentralPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.CentralPager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCentralActivity);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        //Action Bar Stuff

    }

}
```

With this said, I need my CentralPagerAdapter, which I created as follows.

```
public class CentralPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int nSwipes = 3;

    public CentralPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new CentralFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(CentralFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return nSwipes;
    }
}
```

And now, my fragment, which is only a class that contains all of my views, and options and so on.

```
public class CentralFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";
    private View rootView;
    private RESTFunction currentFunction;
    //Has the info I want
    private ArrayList<Integer> tickets = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    private Handler threadConnectionHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (currentFunction) {
                case GET_CLIENT_TICKETS:
                    handleGetTickets(msg);
                    break;
                case BUY_CLIENT_TICKETS:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Bundle args = getArguments();
        handleFragments(inflater, container);
        getTicketInfo(null);    
        return rootView;
    }

    private void handleFragments(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {

        Bundle args = getArguments();

        if (args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT) == 1) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_tickets,
                    container, false);
            showTicketsHandler();
        } else if (args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT) == 2) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buy_tickets,
                    container, false);
            buyTicketsHandler();
        } else {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history_tickets,
                    container, false);
        }
    }

    public void showTicketsHandler() {
        //Get stuff from the tickets array that the REST call will handle
        //And set them to boxes or radio buttons
    }

    public void buyTicketsHandler() {
        //Get stuff from the tickets array that the REST call will handle
        //And set them to boxes or radio buttons
        //As well as button click listeners
    }

    public void getTicketInfo(ProgressDialog progDialog) {
        //Connect to the thread to get the information
        //In this case, I have no parameters
        ConnectionThread dataThread = new ConnectionThread("myLink", Method.GET, null, threadConnectionHandler, progDialog);
        dataThread.start();
    }

    //Get stuff from the resulting JSON and store it in the tickets ArrayList
    private void handleGetTickets(Message msg) {
    JSONObject ticketListing = (JSONObject) msg.obj;
        try {
            tickets.add(ticketListing.getInt("t1"));
            tickets.add(ticketListing.getInt("t2"));
            tickets.add(ticketListing.getInt("t3"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And then, I have my thread..

```
public class ConnectionThread extends Thread {

    private ConnectionRunnable runConnection;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private ProgressDialog progDialog;

    public ConnectionThread(String link, Method method, ArrayList<NameValuePair> payload, Handler handler, ProgressDialog progDialog) {
        runConnection = new ConnectionRunnable(link, method.toString(), payload);
        mHandler = handler;
        this.progDialog = progDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runConnection.run();
        threadMsg();

        if(progDialog != null)
            progDialog.dismiss();
    }

    public JSONObject getJSON() {
        return runConnection.getResultObject();
    }

    private void threadMsg() {
        Message msgObj = mHandler.obtainMessage();
        msgObj.obj = getJSON();
        mHandler.sendMessage(msgObj);
    }

}
```

And ConnectionRunnable is where I run my HttpURLConnection.

**SO WHAT DO I NEED?**

Basically, what I'm trying to do, is to get the ticket information from the ConnectionThread *BEFORE* I load all my view and update them. Plus, I want to be able to swipe back and forth, and update my information on the array as I swipe through the screens (if I go to the second screen, the tickets will update, and if I come back to the first, they will re-update). So basically, call the ConnectionThread everytime I swipe around. If that is possible that, is.

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED?**

I've tried several things already, and all of them didn't actually help..

- The usage of ProgressDialogs to stop the UI Thread on the onCreateView method of the fragment (no use, because it returns the rootView before it handles everything);
- Making the UI Thread sleep for 1 second (I don't know why, it blocks all of them);
- Overriding the instantiateMethod() of the Adapter, although I think I didn't do it correctly;
- Overriding the saveState() of the Adapter, in order to prevent its saved states, and to then get new ticket information;
- Giving the fragments tags to update their rootViews on the Adapter, but to no avail;
- Getting the information in the activity, and everytime I make a purchase (second fragment), restart the whole activity to get the tickets, which I believe is a really, really bad solution.

I've read several articles, and I still couldn't find my answers.. It's really frustrating. Because it's something so simple, however, the fact that I have to run the HTTP calls on a different thread delays the whole UI updating process.

I've also read the AsyncTask's method. However, I feel like both Threads and AsyncTasks end up in the same.

**WHAT TO DO NOW?**

Well, that's what I was hoping to find. Because it ends up being annoying as it is.

**POSSIBLE REASONS**

Is it because I'm separating all classes into spread files, therefore making my work difficult?

Thank you for your time, guys, hope we can find a solution or something.

### **THE EDIT**

So basically, after 4 hours of reading documents and tutorials, I figured that what I needed was setOffscreenPageLimit(`int`). However, it can't be set to 0, so I will have to do with a setOnPageChangeListener. Now, to figure how to refresh the fragment, and I'll be as good as new.

Alright, it works perfectly! Basically, I did this:

```
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    ((CentralFragment)((CentralPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter()).instantiateItem(mViewPager, position)).refresh();
                    getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });
```

Where my .refresh is:

```
public void refresh() {
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT) == 0) {
        getTicketInfo(0);
    } else if (args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT) == 1) {
        getTicketInfo(1);
        buyTicketsHandler();
    } else {
        //To Handle Later
    }       
}
```

It's as simple as refreshing the page before you go to it. Why didn't I remember this before..? So, here's the reference for those who ever need this!

Comment: I'd recommend using an AsyncTask, It'll end up being simpler for you in the end as it just returns to the UI thread so you can update it http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads

Comment: I got the answer, Eluvatar. You can check above. Thanks for the heads up, though, I managed to use the `Threads` anyway. Next time, I will go for `AsyncTask`.